# IDEA выделение блока

Tags: intellij-idea

Что то нажал в IDEA и теперь выделение не обычное (построчное), а "блочное".
Если зажать мишь и опустить вниз и право, выделяться не попавшие в зону строки, а только символы, попавшие в очерченный квадрат. Как это отключить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В меню "Edit" снимите галочку с "Column Selection Mode"

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html#column_selection